# Redirection in aspx page of MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am replacing a website that was written in conventional asp.net with an MVC system

A third party system we use and cannot easily change is expecting to be able to use a url of the format

http://website url here/?searchtype=both&param1=value1&param2=value2

I need to redirect this to

http://website url here/Home/FindByIdentifier?searchtype=both&param1=value1&param2=value2

How can I do this?  Its kind of a redirect to action?

If this is complicated, is this kind of thing possible within Azure which is where the system will now be hosted, as an app service?

Its basically a case of making the third party system still function as though nothing has been changed

My new application uses C# MVC5 with Razor views

Paul

Comment: A custom route should handle that just fine for you.

Comment: Are there any examples you can think of am new to this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this added to your home controller

```
public ActionResult Here()
{
   var url = $"Home/FindByIdentifier{Request.Url.Query}";
   return Redirect(url);
}
```

Comment: Would I call this method search? I can’t check right now

Comment: The overriding issue here is that my legacy system expects to find a file called index.aspx?  The solutions listed here involve modifying my homecontroller which wouldnt be called by the legacy system?  This will call index.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but, apparently, routing rules ignore `get` parameters. I've tried getting to the point of applying regex as constraints and it really ignores `get` parameters.

I'm all about using routes to properly, well, route the request. If someone knows how to do this using `get` params, please let me know.

So, even though I tried not going the redirect alternative, I think that it's the best choice so far.
Consider this on your `HomeController`:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request.QueryString != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString.Value) && System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Request.QueryString.Value, @"^\?searchtype\=both(\&.+\=.+)*$"))
            return Redirect($"/home/FindByIdentifier{Request.QueryString.Value}");

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult FindByIdentifier()
    {
        var getParameters = Request.QueryString.Value;//?searchtype=both&param1=value1&param2=value2
        return View();
    }
```